# php mysqli update query

Tags: php

I have the following php script to update my db, but it doesn't work.
the two echo's show in the ui that the variables are filled with correct values.
The query doensn't seem to be executed though. I don't get any errors whatsoever.

```
<?
    $rapportId = $_GET['variable1'];
    $rapportNaam = $_GET['variable2'];

    echo "rapportId = ". $rapportId;
    echo "<br>rapportNaam = ".$rapportNaam;     

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "twrwe", "twrewtww", "trwtw");

  $mysqli->query("Update Rapporten Set RapportNaam = $rapportNaam
                  Where RapportId = $rapportId
        ")or die(mysqli_error($db));
  $mysqli->commit();
    if ($mysqli->error) {
       printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
  mysqli_free_result();
?>
```

Comment: You also might want to look into protection against [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Have a look at [using prepared statements in mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **prepared statements** for any data coming to the query

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Rapporten SET RapportNaam = ? WHERE RapportId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $rapportNaam, $rapportId);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: $mysqli is an object here and does not need the connection string in the query() check here http://in3.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: tx, had to be a small thing ;)

Comment: More interesting is why `$mysqli->query("Update ...")` is not failing and calling die()

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE `tbl_name` SET `column1`='$column1',`column2`='$column2' WHERE email='$email ;
```

Comment: Additionaly, this query is widely open for SQL injection and should not be used in any current project

Comment: @NicoHaase both answers are open to injection under the assumption that no previous validation was done. Literally both the same answers, different formats lol

Comment: Why this very bad answer is still here? It needs only 2 delete votes more.