# Why is my SQL query not putting data into database?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so Im taking parsed text from webpages and placing it in a column called adtext. Thescripts runs with no errors and says its putting the data in there, but when I manually check the rows are empty! I have run a `var_dump` after the `return_between()` and the text is there, but its not making it into the DB. Here is the code so far...

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    $link_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link_result);


    file_get_contents($result['adlink']);
    $text_holder = file_get_contents($result['adlink']);

    return_between($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->", EXCL);
    $final_text = return_between($text_holder, "postingBody", "<!-- .posting -->", EXCL);

    $query2 = "UPDATE usedcars SET adtext = $final_text WHERE `key` = $x";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

    echo "<font color='#FFFF00'>Placing text from <font color='#00FF00'>$result[adlink]</font> into database</font><br>"; 

    $x++;
    }
```

What am I missing/forgetting?

Comment: It doesn't work because you forgot `mysqli_error()` after the UPDATE query.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 `$final_text` is a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322364/php-mysqli-update-query

Comment: ok i will @Arif_suhail_123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing single quete around `$final_text`,

```
$query2 = "UPDATE usedcars SET adtext = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $final_text)."' WHERE `key`= $x";
```

and always notify your self with error **In Production**. by using `mysqli_error()` like this

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error());
```

`mysqli` does not automatically secure your query use `bindparam`

Comment: Also, what its showing me is that the string Im inputting contains quotes...is there a way to have it ignore everything inside the `$final_text` variable and just put it in the db? @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: Yes, it says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near(actual text being input->) car is 5'4" and I'm sure it will fit most passengers    @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: with or without is fine @Arif_suhail_123